# Need to read Parameter from redirect in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to redirect myself to another page but passing an argument as I can do using render template. However with the redirect, my html doesn´t receive the variable I need to send.

Here you can see my flask code:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def receivesearch():
    busqueda=request.form['search']
    #aqui se obtiene el resultado de la busqueda
    print(busqueda)
    return redirect(url_for('upload_file', valorbusqueda=busqueda))
    #return render_template('main.html', valorbusqueda=busqueda)
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="search-container">
    <form action="/search" method=post>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar.." name="search">
      <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
        <h1 style="text-align: left">Usted busco: {{ valorbusqueda }}</h1>
    </form>
  </div>
```

My code for upload is:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file(valorbusqueda):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #Llamar aqui las funciones que se tienen que hacer antes de mostrar la data
            os.rename(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), r'static/uploadfiles/import.json')
            return redirect(url_for('upload_file', valorbusqueda="", filename=filename))

    if (valorbusqueda is None):
        valorbusqueda=""

    return render_template('main.html', valorbusqueda=valorbusqueda)
```

But I am getting the follow error when I open the webpage:

```
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: upload_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'valorbusqueda'
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's your  code for  your`upload_file` view? Do you pass `valorbusqueda` to `render_template` in this view?

Comment: @PGHE, I edited my post with that part of the code.

Comment: Do you need `valorbusqueda` to be part of the URL or a parameter i.e. `domain/valorbusqueda` or `domain?valorbusqueda=abc`?

Comment: No, I only need to pass the value to my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the value in the URL paramters, i.e. `domain?valorbusqueda='abc'`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file(): # Removed valorbusqueda

    valorbusqueda = request.args.get('valorbusqueda', '')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...

    return render_template('main.html', valorbusqueda=valorbusqueda)
```